# Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_header() in index.php on line 1

Tags: undefined, fatal-error

I have the same issue. I am totally new in PHP. I installed [XAMPP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XAMPP) and downloaded the hatch theme from WordPress. When I run index.php it gives me the following error

> "Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_header() in C:\xampp\htdocs\hatch\index.php on line 1"

How can I fix this?

Comment: i dont beleive this is off topic

Answer (score 39):

It appears that you're trying to run a WordPress theme outside of an installation of WordPress.

You need to download a copy of [WordPress](http://wordpress.org/download), extract it into your `htdocs` folder (like you did with the theme), and then navigate to it in your browser.

After setting it up (just follow the instructions), you need to place that theme in `wp-content/themes` inside the WordPress install.

Then, you can change the theme to your new one in your WordPress administrator panel.

Answer (score 12):

You are just accessing the theme file. That's the reason for the error.

First you need to include the theme file you downloaded into the WordPress installation folder: `wp-content/themes`

Then activate the theme from the administrator dashboard. Now you can use the theme.

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to access the theme file directly from XAMPP'S `htdocs` folder.

Copy the theme file, and add it to `htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes`. Run WordPress and add the theme from the administrator dashboard.