# Pass query string from one page to another in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a custom template page in wordpress named "batches.php" which contains the following codes

```
echo '<a href="'.get_template_directory_uri().'/view-batches.php?bid=58233b48dbc43" >View</a>';
```

The code above sends bid=58233b48dbc43 to "view-batches.php" .

view-batches.php :

```
<?php 
/* Template name:View Batches */
echo "Batch id=".$_GET["bid"];
get_header();
get_footer();
?>
```

This codes print the value of bid i.e. 58233b48dbc43 but also shows a 
Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_header()

Any solution for this problem and also how to pass a data from one page to another in wordpress

Comment: include wodpress file to use its functions require_once("wp-load.php");

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fatal error: Call to undefined function get\_header() in index.php on line 1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10062717/fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-get-header-in-index-php-on-line-1)

Comment: That is not working,
eRROR -  Warning: require_once(wp-load.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory....   
@VishnuBhadoriya

Answer (score 0):

This function is located into      `wp-includes/general-template.php`.
 So you just include the above file or make sure it is include in your theme core file