# 500 Internal server error + undefined function get_header()

Tags: jquery

I am working on wordpress and wanna make instant search for my users to get the foods data from database.But 1 problem is getting me mad for like 5 days ...The problem is with Jquery post method,when i want to define the path for the page on which information must be posted it gives me back [this](http://prntscr.com/dr1k1z) error.I tried many MANY things,there are some things which i remember.

1.Downloaded Telerik Fiddled to debug the page(to see if there are other mini errors ).

2.Downloaded a server logs to see requests from there.

3.Tried all kinds of Url's for file path and even tried links to the webpage in which i want info to get posted on.

And i noticed only 1 of all path gives me different error,All paths which i tried were giving me 404 (Not Found),but /wp-content/themes/yuuta/Food-Groups-BG.php this one gives me 500 (Internal Server Error) which i pasted up.
I also noticed that when i put that path into my .js file `error_log` appears in mine main folder,and there is this error:

PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function get_header() in /home/shreddin/public_html/wp-content/themes/yuuta/Food-Groups-BG.php on line 3

There is my jquery:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
 $("#food_search").keyup(function(event){
  var search_term =$(this).val();
  $.post("/wp-content/themes/yuuta/Food-Groups-BG.php",{search_term: search_term},function(data)
   {
    $("#food_search_result").html(data);
   })
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Търсене на храни: <input type="text" name="food-search" id="food_search"></p>
<div id="food_search_result"></div>
```

I really need help,sorry if i have missed something or got any mistake.Thanks in advance !

Comment: Please read the error carefully, it comes from PHP. There's no native `get_header()` but there's [get_headers()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-headers.php).

Comment: I am just saying it for info,i  read in this forum that this error is probably from the server,but what should i do to get it fixed ;/ Thats why i don't know ;)

Comment: What is the content of /home/shreddin/public_html/wp-content/themes/yuuta/Food-Groups-BG.php? Line 3 in that file is what is producing the error.

Comment: Its the worpdress shortcode for calling the header  <?php get_header (); ?>

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fatal error: Call to undefined function get\_header() in index.php on line 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10062717/fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-get-header-in-index-php-on-line-1)

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you use get_header function in your php page(/wp-content/themes/yuuta/Food-Groups-BG.php)

Remove the get_header function from your php page and put the css and jss link relation there.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../wp-content/uploads/custom-css-js/77.css">
<script src="../wp-content/uploads/custom-css-js/139.js"></script>
```

Notice the `../` at the beginning of the path, use this when you are on a page of the website.